# How can I parse an excel sheet that is in html through python?

Tags: python, html, excel

I have an excel sheet that is actually an html table (must have been saved as 'save as webpage' on excel). When I open the .xls in a texteditor, it starts with:

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/ss; charset=windows-1252'><meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet><meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Excel 10'><style>@page {margin:.7in .7in .7in .7in; mso-page-number-start:1; mso-header-data:'&R&B&D &T'; mso-footer-data:'&C&B Page &P of &N'; mso-page-orientation:landscape;  } 
 td.num0 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0;
 } 

 td.num1 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.0;
 } 

 td.num2 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.00;
 } 

 td.num3 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.000;
 } 

 td.num4 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.0000;
 } 

 td.num5 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.00000;
 } 

 td.num6 {
 mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0.000000;
 } 

 td.text {
 mso-number-format:\@;
 } 

 td.date1 {
 mso-number-format:mm\/yyyy;
 } 

 td.date2 {
 mso-number-format:'Short Date';
 } 
</style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <x:ExcelWorkbook>  <x:ExcelWorksheets>   <x:ExcelWorksheet> <x:Name>report1</x:Name>   <x:WorksheetOptions> <x:DisplayPageBreak/>   <x:FitToPage/>  <x:Print>  <x:ValidPrinterInfo/> <x:FitWidth>1</x:FitWidth> <x:FitHeight>990</x:FitHeight>  </x:Print>  <x:Selected/>  <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>  <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>   <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>  </x:WorksheetOptions> <x:PageBreaks> <x:RowBreaks> <x:RowBreak> <x:Row>43</x:Row> </x:RowBreak> </x:RowBreaks>  </x:PageBreaks> </x:ExcelWorksheet>  </x:ExcelWorksheets>    <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>  </x:ExcelWorkbook>  <x:ExcelName>   <x:Name>Print_Titles</x:Name>   <x:SheetIndex>1</x:SheetIndex>  <x:Formula>=report1!$1:$5</x:Formula>   </x:ExcelName> </xml><![endif]--></HEAD><BODY>
```

Is there something I can use to parse this kind of format?

Comment: Did you try to open it in a browser?  If that works, the best way would be to copy the table from your browser into Excel or another spreadsheet app and save it as CSV.  Python has good libraries for dealing with CSV files (and xlsx files too.)

Comment: The excel file is already in an .xls format (but opened in a text editor, the data is written in html). I'm wondering if there is a direct way to parse the data than converting everything to an actual xls (there are a lot of files in this html format)

Comment: There isn't any actual data in the sample that you submitted.  Is that the entire file contents?

There are several XML parsing libraries in Python.  You could use one of those.

Comment: No its just to show beginning of the code. Unfortunately it is not in xml. it is a .xls. Can i use a xml parser to read a .xls?

Comment: Unless you want to write a custom parser, I would try that first.  Depending on the library that you choose it could get you what you want.